# Getting users from dynamic distribution group Exchange 2007/2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2007, powershell

I've found article at [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232019.aspx) claiming that this powershell query would give me a list of users in a dynamic distribution group that is defined more or less like this:

[image]

The code to list:

```
$MarketingGroup = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup "Marketing Group"
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $MarketingGroup.RecipientFilter -OrganizationalUnit $MarketingGroup.OrganizationalUnit
```

So I modified it a bit:

```
$members = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "dynamic group"
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $members.RecipientFilter -OrganizationalUnit $members.OrganizationalUnit | select Displayname,PrimarySmtpAddress > membersall.txt
```

but the problem is my query (and Microsoft for that matter) takes only part of equation into consideration. It takes the radio/checkboxes choice but it seems to be skipping the `Container` the users are in (even thou `$members.OrganizationalUnit` should do the trick). It seems to return everyone with `Users with Exchange mailboxes` that are in the chosen container but it also takes the people which are in default `Users OU`.

So how to modify the query to display only the ones within the recipient container chosen without the default Users OU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong property for `OrganizationalUnit` The following should work:

```
$MarketingGroup = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup "Marketing Group"
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $MarketingGroup.RecipientFilter -OrganizationalUnit $MarketingGroup.RecipientContainer
```

Comment: That's what they proposed on Microsoft website :) I'm having hard time "finding" the right keywords myself.

Comment: Well when I run that here I get the proper listing scoped to the OU defined. Are you not getting that? I'm confused

Comment: The .OrganizationalUnit is the location of the dynamic distribution group, not the scope you defined in the group.

Comment: I'm sure it will work. I'm just saying Microsoft website is wrong and that I knew i have to change the OrganizationalUnit to something and I didn't knew to what. I miss the autocomplete from Visual Studio/Resharper for this kind of thing.

Comment: I did just look on the MS page and they do have misinformation there.

Answer (score 0):

Incase your Dynamic DL was made in Exchange 2003 or prior... or you're running a hybrid environment.  Give this one-liner a crack.  Note the difference is using the LDAPRecipientFilter instead of just RecipientFilter.  In a 2003 environment, the plain RecipientFilter value will be null.

```
Get-Recipient -RecipientPReviewFilter (Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity *groupname*).LDAPRecipientFilter | Select Name,PrimarySMTPAddress
```